# Social sharing count (Specially Facebook and Twitter) when moving to HTTPS

Tags: https, facebook, http, social-media, twitter

How can I get back the social sharing count (Specially Facebook and Twitter) when moving to HTTPS?

Note : WordPress Site (I don't think platform does not related to this question. But if it is related, I am talking about WP site moving HTTP to HTTPS)